# Hows should I structure middleware to verify an ID exists in an external service in a Node/Express app?

Tags: node.js, express

I've currently written middleware to verify an ID exists in an external services (Salesforce). I initially wrote it when it was a single use app, but now I'm trying to make it work with different routes, so I want it to be fairly generic.

I don't even know if middleware is the right way to go, or if I should just call the function before saving the specific form.

I've got a form where someone puts in some information about a project, and the salesforce ID. For background, the salesforce ID is actually an auto-increment number, and I need to convert that to the actual salesforce system ID before I use jsForce to create a new object linked to that ID.

My route looks like this:

```
router.post('/invoice/add', ensureLoggedIn, invoiceController.validateInvoice, catchErrors(sfdc.validateSFID), catchErrors(invoiceController.saveInvoice))
```

So, I've got a middleware that does this:

```
exports.validateSFID = async(req, res, next) => {

  const salesforceProjectNumber = req.body.SF_Opportunity
  const sfResult = await conn.search(`FIND ... long query`, (err, result) => {
    if (err || result.searchRecords.length !== 1) {
      req.flash('error', 'Unable to find a Salesforce Job with that ID number.')
      console.error(`ERROR: ${req.user.displayName} errored when looking up job number ${salesforceProjectNumber}.`)
      return result
    }
  })
  if (sfResult.searchRecords.length > 0) {
    req.body.salesforce_Opportunity_id = sfResult.searchRecords[0].Id //Create a generic variable to hold the salesforce opportunity so it works regardless of the custom object name
    res.locals.Opportunity_Clean_Name = sfResult.searchRecords[0].Name
  }
  next()
}
```

The query rarely throws an error, but in this case, an error is basically returning !1 records.

When that happens, I want to flash a message on the screen saying the ID wasn't found, but keep the form filled in.

When an ID is found, I want to proceed to save it and NOT display the form fields anymore.

This middleware needs to work regardless of the form I'm using, I want to be able to pipe in the middleware from any form that might require a user to enter a salesforce job as a field.

Any thoughts on how best to handle it all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your middleware by using `app.use()` function

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // Every time a request has made, this middleware will fire
  console.log('Howdy');
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I can get the middleware working, as in called, but I'm just not sure what the best way is to structure it to throw an error flash if it can't find the ID. It needs to throw it on the form that submitted it, along with the data that it tried to post in the first place. Should I just be adding something to res.locals and processing it before I render it out?

Comment: I know there a module that work with flash messages very well, https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-flash